# Is the planet Alastria located in the Delta quadrant?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the episode "Prime Factors", Harry Kim is transported to Alastria which is 40 thousand light years away from the planet they are on. So is the planet Alastria still in the delta quadrant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alastria), there has been quite a bit of debate over it.  But it seems to be yes, it's in the Delta quadrant.

> While the Sikarians explained that they could reach all planets in their quadrant, it was not explicitly said, and nor does it follow, that Alastria too was in the Delta Quadrant. However, according to Startrek.com and the Star Trek Encyclopedia (3rd ed., p. 5), this planet was located in this quadrant.

This from [Startrek.com](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/alastria):

> A Delta Quadrant planet with a binary star about 40,000 light-years from Sikaris, accessed via the spatial trajector.

So assuming that the Star Trek Encyclopedia is the most accurate source of information, then you can say yes it is :)